# Python Scrapy & Yield

Tags: python, scrapy

I am currently developing a scraper using Scrapy for the first time and I am using Yield for the first time as well. I am still trying to wrap my head around yield.

The Scraper:

- Scrapes one page to get a list of dates (parse)
- Uses these dates to format URLS to then scrape (parse_page_contents)
- On this page, it find URLS of each individual listing and scrapes the individual listings (parse_page_listings)
- On the individual list I want to extract all the data. There are also 4 links on each individual listing that contains even more data.  (parse_individual_listings)

I am struggling to understand how to combine the JSON from  parse_individual_tabs and parse_individual_listings into one JSON string. This will be one for each individual listing and will be sent to an API. Even just printing it for the time being will work.

```
    class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"

    start_urls = [
            '',
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.css('table.apas_tbl tr').extract()
        for row in rows[1:]:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(row, 'lxml')
            dates = soup.find_all('input')
            url = ""
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page_contents)

    def parse_page_contents(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="apas_form"]').extract_first()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
        pages = soup.find(id='apas_form_text')
        urls = []
        urls.append(response.url)
        for link in pages.find_all('a'):
            urls.append('/'.format(link['href']))

        for url in urls:
             yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page_listings)

    def parse_page_listings(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="apas_form"]').extract_first()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
        resultTable = soup.find("table", { "class" : "apas_tbl" })

        for row in resultTable.find_all('a'):
            url = ""
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_individual_listings)


    def parse_individual_listings(self, response): 
        rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="apas_form"]').extract_first() 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
        fields = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'fieldset_data'})
        for field in fields:
            print field.label.text.strip()
            print field.p.text.strip()

        tabs = response.xpath('//div[@id="tabheader"]').extract_first() 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(tabs, 'lxml')
        links = soup.find_all("a")
       for link in links:
            yield scrapy.Request( urlparse.urljoin(response.url, link['href']), callback=self.parse_individual_tabs)
```

To:

```
def parse_individual_listings(self, response): 
    rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="apas_form"]').extract_first() 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
    fields = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'fieldset_data'})
    data = {}
    for field in fields:
        data[field.label.text.strip()] = field.p.text.strip()

    tabs = response.xpath('//div[@id="tabheader"]').extract_first() 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(tabs, 'lxml')
    links = soup.find_all("a")
    for link in links:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            urlparse.urljoin(response.url, link['href']), 
            callback=self.parse_individual_tabs,
            meta={'data': data}
        )
    print data
```

..

```
    def parse_individual_tabs(self, response): 
        data = {}
        rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="tabContent"]').extract_first() 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
        fields = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'fieldset_data'})
        for field in fields:
            data[field.label.text.strip()] = field.p.text.strip()

        print json.dumps(data)
```

to

```
def parse_individual_tabs(self, response): 
        data = {}
        rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="tabContent"]').extract_first() 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
        fields = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'fieldset_data'})
        for field in fields:
            data[field.label.text.strip()] = field.p.text.strip()

        yield json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: do you want to yield an individual item that gets the information you have in `parse_individual_tabs` and `parse_individual_listings`?

Comment: I would like the data from parse_individual_tabs and everything thats prinited from parse_individual_listings to be combined into one JSON object for each time parse_individual_listings is called. (I hope that makes sense)

Answer (score 5):

Normally when obtaining data, you'll have to use [`Scrapy Items`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) but they can also be replaced with dictionaries (which would be the JSON objects you are referring to), so we'll use them now:

First, start creating the item (or dictionary) in the `parse_individual_listings` method, just as you did with `data` in `parse_individual_tabs`. Then pass it to the next request (that will be caught by `parse_individual_tabs` with the [`meta`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) argument, so it should look like:

```
def parse_individual_listings(self, response):
    ...
    data = {}
    data[field1] = 'data1'
    data[field1] = 'data2'
    ...
    yield scrapy.Request(
        urlparse.urljoin(response.url, link['href']), 
        callback=self.parse_individual_tabs,
        meta={'data': data};
    )
```

Then, you can get that data in `parse_individual_tabs`:

```
def parse_individual_tabs(self, response):
    data = response.meta['data']
    ...
    # keep populating `data`
    yield data
```

Now the `data` in `parse_individual_tabs` has all the information you want from both requests, you can do the same between any callback requests.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Is it possible instead of 'yielding' to parse_individual tabs just to call it from parse_individual_listings and return the JSON to parse_individual_listings so this will have the complete JSON ?

Comment: so only collect the information you get in `parse_individual_listings`? Yes, that is the good thing about `yield`, you can yield the times you want from a method, so just `yield data` and in then `yield Request(..)` in the same method.

Comment: Could you explain it a bit further please? I tried to change it but am getting ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'str'  now. I will update the question with the new code I am using.

Comment: as the message says, yield `data` directly, don't transform it to string.