# Python Scrapy and yielding

Tags: python, scrapy

This is a follow on from question [Python Scrapy & Yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936117/python-scrapy-yield?noredirect=1#comment69083895_40936117)

I am currently developing a scraper using Scrapy for the first time and I am using Yield for the first time as well. I am getting very very confused about how yield works.

The Scraper:

1. Scrapes one page to get a list of date ranges
2. Uses these dates ranges to format URLS to then scrape another page which contains listings which are paginated into groups of 10 listings
3. I would like to scrap all these urls that link to 10 listings
4. Then on these pages I would like to scrap all the listings and extract data from them. These individual listings also have 4 'tabs' that need to be scraped.

   ```
   class MyScraper(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "myscraper"

   start_urls = [
   ]


   def parse(self, response):
       rows = response.css('table.apas_tbl tr').extract()
       for row in rows[1:]:
           soup = BeautifulSoup(row, 'lxml')
           url = soup.find_all("a")[1]['href']
           yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page_contents)

   def parse_page_contents(self, response):
       rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="apas_form"]').extract_first()
       soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
       pages = soup.find(id='apas_form_text')
       for link in pages.find_all('a'):
           url = link['href']
           yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page_listings)

   def parse_page_listings(self, response):
       rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="apas_form"]').extract_first()
       soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
       resultTable = soup.find("table", { "class" : "apas_tbl" })

       for row in resultTable.find_all('a'):
           url = row['href']
           yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_individual_listings)


   def parse_individual_listings(self, response): 
       rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="apas_form"]').extract_first() 
       soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
       fields = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'fieldset_data'})
       data = {}
       for field in fields:
           data[field.label.text.strip()] = field.p.text.strip()

       tabs = response.xpath('//div[@id="tabheader"]').extract_first() 
       soup = BeautifulSoup(tabs, 'lxml')
       links = soup.find_all("a")
       for link in links:
           yield scrapy.Request(
               urlparse.urljoin(response.url, link['href']), 
               callback=self.parse_individual_tabs,
               meta={'data': data}
           )
        print data

   def parse_individual_tabs(self, response): 
       data = {}
       rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="tabContent"]').extract_first() 
       soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
       fields = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'fieldset_data'})
       for field in fields:
           data[field.label.text.strip()] = field.p.text.strip()

       yield json.dumps(data)
   ```

The scraper currently seems to be somewhat working with issues though. The main concern at the moment is:

> ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'str' in

also there is some duplication of urls that are scraped. I am wondering (a) what is causing the error above and (b) does the yield set up appear to be formatted correctly?

Comment: You do not have to use `yield`: you can simply construct a list where you store all the `yield`ed elements into and return the list.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem while you are correct, it's more convenient and generally a better idea to `yield` values instead of storing them to temporal list and then returning the whole list. Not only `yield` looks better but using `yield` instead of `return` turns the function into a generator which performs better.

Comment: @Granitosaurus: yeah, I use `yield` all the time (despite being the only one that likes it at my workpace). It is also better for memory (say you emit a million objects each taking a few megabytes then a list cannot store them). But in this case the learning curve is probably less steep when using lists.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning string in one of your parse methods:

```
def parse_individual_tabs(self, response): 
    data = {}
    rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="tabContent"]').extract_first() 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
    fields = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'fieldset_data'})
    for field in fields:
        data[field.label.text.strip()] = field.p.text.strip()

    yield json.dumps(data)  #<---- here
```

As the error message says:

> ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'str' in

So just `yield data` instead since data is a dict.

Edit:
Regarding your second issue - there's an issue with your last two parse methods:

```
def parse_individual_listings(self, response): 
    # <..>
    data = {}
    for field in fields:
        data[field.label.text.strip()] = field.p.text.strip()

    # <..>
    for link in links:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            urlparse.urljoin(response.url, link['href']), 
            callback=self.parse_individual_tabs,
            meta={'data': data}  # <-- you carry data here to below
        )

def parse_individual_tabs(self, response): 
    data = {}  # <--- here's the issue
    # instead you should retrieve data carried from above:
    data = response.meta['data']
    # <..>
    for field in fields:
        data[field.label.text.strip()] = field.p.text.strip()
    return data  # also cine there's only 1 element you can just return it instead of yielding, it makes no difference
```

Comment: Thank you for that. That fixed the error. However, now the information from each 'tab' appears on its own. It doesn't appear to be concatenated to the data dict in parse_individual_listings. Is there an error in my yield structure?

Comment: @19421608 right I see, check out my edit regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

you are yielding the request in parse_individual_listings so No need to yield the data in parse_individual_tabs. because generators are lazy so need return to run it.

Corrected Code:

```
import json
```

from urllib.parse import urljoin

import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class MyScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myscraper"

```
start_urls = [
]

def parse(self, response):
    rows = response.css('table.apas_tbl tr').extract()
    for row in rows[1:]:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(row, 'lxml')
        url = soup.find_all("a")[1]['href']
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page_contents)

def parse_page_contents(self, response):

    rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="apas_form"]').extract_first()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
    pages = soup.find(id='apas_form_text')
    for link in pages.find_all('a'):
        url = link['href']
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page_listings)


def parse_page_listings(self, response):
    rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="apas_form"]').extract_first()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
    resultTable = soup.find("table", {"class": "apas_tbl"})

    for row in resultTable.find_all('a'):
        url = row['href']
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_individual_listings)


def parse_individual_listings(self, response):
    rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="apas_form"]').extract_first()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
    fields = soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'fieldset_data'})
    data = {}
    for field in fields:
        data[field.label.text.strip()] = field.p.text.strip()

    tabs = response.xpath('//div[@id="tabheader"]').extract_first()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(tabs, 'lxml')
    links = soup.find_all("a")
    for link in links:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            urljoin(response.url, link['href']),
            callback=self.parse_individual_tabs,
            meta={'data': data}
        )
    print
    data


def parse_individual_tabs(self, response):
    data = {}
    rows = response.xpath('//div[@id="tabContent"]').extract_first()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(rows, 'lxml')
    fields = soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'fieldset_data'})
    for field in fields:
        data[field.label.text.strip()] = field.p.text.strip()

    return json.dumps(data)
```